# Spark- Why do I get a NPE when write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite) even if the dataframe allows other actions as first or show?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns which has got a schema similar to this:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(UUID,StringType,true), StructField(NAME,StringType,true), StructField(DOCUMENT,ArrayType(MapType(StringType,StringType,true),true),true))
```

This could be a sample of a row in this dataframe:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [11223344,ALAN,28,WrappedArray(Map(source -> central, document_number -> 1234, first_seen -> 2018-05-01))]
```

I am generating a new column after applying a udf function over the last column of this dataframe. The one which is and Array>

This is the code I am applying:

```
def number_length( num:String ) : String = { if(num.length < 6) "000000" else num }

def validating_doc = udf((inputSeq: Seq[Map[String, String]]) => {
  inputSeq.map(x => Map("source" -> x("source"),"document_number" -> number_length(x("document_number")),"first_seen"-> x("first_seen"))))
})

val newDF = DF.withColumn("VALID_DOCUMENT", validating_doc($"DOCUMENT"))
```

After this everything works fine and I can perform some actions like show and `first`, which returns:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [11223344,ALAN,28,WrappedArray(Map(source -> central, document_number -> 1234, first_seen -> 2018-05-01)),WrappedArray(Map(source -> central, document_number -> 000000, first_seen -> 2018-05-01))]
```

But if I try to write as an avro this Dataframe, doing like this:

```
newDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("hdfs:///data/mypath")
```

I get the following error:

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, myserver.azure.com): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at $line101.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$validating_doc$1.apply(<console>:52)
        at $line101.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$validating_doc$1.apply(<console>:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:263)
```

But if I drop this new column, it is possible to write the dataframe.

What am I missing when writting the dataframe? is the udf changing something in the schema that I am not aware of?

Comment: check if you can write using csv format. if yes then its must be issue with avro formatter

Comment: Ok I will try that

Comment: @Ramesh Hi, how is it possible to solve the problem with the avro formatter?

Comment: what happened with the csv formatter?

Comment: Giving me another sort of issues since I lack those libraries in my server. Trying to install them now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code gives NPE in the `UDF` call. Function you use is not `null`-safe, it will fail if:

- `inputSeq` is `null`.
- Any element of `inputSeq` is `null`.
- Any `document_number` number is `null` in any element of `inputSeq` is `null`.

It would also fail if any item was missing (although it is not a problem here. You have to include proper checks, starting with something like this (not tested):

```
def number_length( num:String ) : String = num match { 
  case null => null
  case _ => if(num.length < 6) "000000" else num 
}


def validating_doc = udf((inputSeq: Seq[Map[String, String]]) => inputSeq match {
  case null => null
  case xs => xs.map {
    case null => null
    case x => Map(
      "source" -> x("source"),
      "document_number" ->  number_length(x("document_number")),
      "first_seen" -> x("first_seen")
    )
  }
})
```

> Why do I get a NPE when write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite) even if the dataframe allows other actions as first or show?

Because both `first` and `show` evaluate only a subset of data and clearly don't hit problematic row.

Comment: Thanks I was almost sure that was the issue. I tried, without success handle possible null cases in the df. What I didn't know was show only evaluates a subset. I though it evaluates all to display just a subset. Last thing I would like to ask, what if document_number or first_seen is null? How could I make sure it will not fail then?

Comment: I think, the snippet I included should already covers that case. If `number_length` gets `null` it returns `null`, and it is acceptable return type here.

Comment: sorry I wrote wrong and edit too late. I mean for the cases where I am not calling number_length, that is source and first_seen. Will the "first_seen" -> x("first_seen") fail in case it is null?

Comment: It shouldn't. `null` field is just fine. We are only worried about cases where value is further processed.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!